# Usage of mapreduce in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection which looks like:

```
{
  id : 0,
  power: 10
}

{
  id : 0,
  power : 20
}

{
  id : 0,
  power : 5
}

{
  id : 1,
  power: 100
}

{
  id : 1,
  power : 3
}

...
```

So I need to query 2 documents per id with max power. For example, as a result I should get 2 documents with `id = 0` which powers are **10** and **20**. With `id=1` I get documents where powers are **100** and **3**. Is it possible to do this with simple aggregation or I have to use mapReduce. And what's the right way of doing this?

Comment: Really not sure what you are asking here. Do you want to get all of the documents with the same "id" value merged into one per "id" value? Or do you want just "two" results  only per "id" value, regardless of how many share the same "id" value? Note that this is not "_id" of course since those all must be unique.

Comment: @NeilLunn I need just two result only per one "id". There could be 100 documents with `id = 0` but I need to get only 2 of them with the biggest `power` field. And this logic for each unique `id`.

Comment: It's not an uncommon question. There are a couple of approaches in the answer to the other question. Depending on your needs you might find this simpler to implement with separate queries. The JIRA issue mentioned there could do with some up-votes to make this easier.

Comment: I think you just need to sort and limit: db.yourcollection.find({'id':0}).sort({'power':-1}).limit(2)